# Parse Error in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, publish, parse-error

I first published the website locally without precompiling it. (Precompile generates another error: Can't find the valid AspnetMergePath) And then I transfered it using FTP to the server. I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is there an attachement to using a website? Converting it to a web application might serve you better. You'll compile it locally and deploy the bits.

Comment: Does it build? The codebehind file contains the class this page will inherit from. That class should be compiled into an assembly in the bin folder. When you view the page, .net will look in the bin folder for an assembly containing the `load` class. It can't find it, so you see that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your solution different assemblies .NET version compatibility. This looks like that kind of error, where app is not able to load an assembly

- or because it can not be located [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx)
- or because there is different .NET versions comaptibility issue.

Comment: Where can someone set version compatibility settings?

Comment: @jayt.dev: I probabbly not explained good myself. I mean target .NET framework version compatibility.

Comment: @jayt.dev: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

Comment: FYI: local verion4.0.30319.233   server:4.0.30319.18051 I don't know if this means anything to you!

Comment: The version stuff seems legit, so may be issue is that program is not able simply *locate* assembly it reports.

Comment: I am trying to understand how it locates assemlies

Comment: @jayt.dev: see where that type declared, check if *it is* actually present in assembly you deployed, used some IL disassembler (for example: http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), check if that assembly actually present in local directory of your site or in GAC of your server.

Comment: wow too much info to proccess! I can see no reason why the assembly is not present. It is a very small hello world project. There is just one aspx web form and the relative .cs file

Comment: @jayt.dev: so check if specified type is actually present in assembly you deploy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the corrensponding .cs file is also moved by the FTP. It looks like it can't find the corrensponding extractDataTest.cs file containing the Load method.

Comment: When I publish the site there is no .cs file

Comment: Doesn't look to be a website, as there's no codefile attribute, so the .cs file wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

May be the designer page is missing.Try to send three files of this load page.

```
aspx, aspx.cs and designer page.
```

Comment: a deployed page doesn't need those files. Also void wild guesses.